# ngAnimate only degrades partially in IE9

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, internet-explorer-9, ng-animate

I've modified code from [this tutorial](http://blog.assaf.co/native-slide-toggle-for-angularjs-1-4-x/) which animates a sliding `div` so that it works as a toggling menu. I was hoping it would degrade into normal hide-show in IE9. Which it is. But only one time. If I click the first button, it will toggle its div on and off. It works for all four like that. But after that first toggle, IE fails to show the `div`s again. I can verify that the `ng-click` is working through logging the index of the clicked button. For some reason though, it appears that the `display` property isn't being set to `block`. Is there a known issue where ngAnimate causes IE9 to break without an error, or have I missed something obvious?

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/tuhaquyori/edit?html,css,js,output)

Comment: have Jquery included in your page ?

Comment: @IsmailFarooq yes, I have

Comment: @thomas I know it's not related to your ques, but buddy, are you still caring about IE9 & older versions? ;)
If you still need it to support then do include some modernizer libraries to make it work.!

Comment: hey @thomas did you try this.....https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[In angularjs site](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_12) you will find this:

> Although most modern browsers have good support for CSS transitions
>   and CSS animations, IE9 and earlier do not. If you want animations
>   that are backwards-compatible with older browsers, consider using
>   JavaScript-based animations, which are described in detail below.

practical: if you remove this line : `transition: all 0.8s;` you will see that all the browsers behave the same way.

Solutions:

Internet Explorer 9 was the last of the IE browsers to not support the transition property, or animations as you can see [here](http://caniuse.com/#search=transitions), but is support conditional comments, so you could put fallback code into an IE9-only conditional comment, and deliver that as your solution to all IE9 (and below) users.

```
<!--[if lte IE 9]>
    <script src="animation-legacy-support.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Or you can use the modernizr library like this:

```
if(!Modernizr.csstransitions) { // if not supported.
//ADD YOUR javascirpt-based CODE HERE
}
```

or you can just make all the animation with jquery, use jquery 2.x for ie9+ or jquery 1.x for ie6+ as you can see [here](https://jquery.com/browser-support/).

Note: An example with angular and jquery animation can be found in [Animating ngClass with JavaScript](http://Animating%20ngClass%20with%20JavaScript) chapter in angularjs site, in the bottom.

Comment: Very delightful answer Tom!

Comment: Thanks Tom. Good to know these are the best options.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know css transitions are not supported in IE9 and earlier. So if you want to support these browsers you might use jQuery animations instead.

Hope this would be helpful.